# Getting The Proper Name Value Instead Of Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, field

I am using the following code to get users from a SharePoint list:

```
private ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
private SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("SharePoint List");
private CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
private ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
private ArrayList names = new ArrayList();
clientContext.Load(collListItem, items => items.Include(
        item => item["UserNames"]));
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
        {
            titles.Add(oListItem["UserNames"]);
        }
```

I am retrieving data from another columns, too, and I get those data just fine. But when it comes to names, the return value is the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldUserValue`.

Any suggestions on how to get the actual usernames?

Comment: when you use the debugger .. can you put a  breakpoint on the 
`titles.Add(oListItem["UserNames"]);` inside the quick watch and see what properties you can get at in `oListItem["UserNames"]` perhaps there is another indexed position if so then you should do a for loop but can't really tell without knowing the datastructure

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's supposed to return FieldUserValue, you can get the users name or ID from the object.  Here's a quick example:

```
FieldUserValue user = (FieldUserValue)listItem["Author"];
string name = user.LookupValue;
```

Comment: Lookups, Taxonomy (Managed Metadata), and People Pickers all require casting in CSOM to get the right values.  Glad this helped!